# how to store handler result into JsonArray vertx?

Tags: java, vert.x

I am facing a problem,I can't store the handler result into Json Array.Every time the array is empty . I tried to use Future but it still the same problem, here is my code :

```
 static void getCaraReferTypeDocBin(RoutingContext routingContext){
    String ids =  routingContext.request().getParam("ids");
    logger.debug(ids);
    String[] idsArray = ids.split(",");
    JsonArray caraRefTypeDocBin = new JsonArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <idsArray.length ; i++) {
        GET.getCaraTypeDocBin(Integer.parseInt(idsArray[i]), res->{
           if (res.succeeded()){
               logger.debug(res.result());
               caraRefTypeDocBin.add(res.result());
           }else{
               logger.debug(res.cause().getMessage());
           }
       });

    }
    logger.debug(caraRefTypeDocBin);
}
```

this  is `getCaraReferTypeDocBin` implementation :

```
 public static void getCaraTypeDocBin(int id ,Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> resultHandler) {
    JsonArray pIn = new JsonArray();
    pIn.add(new JsonObject().put("pos", 2).put("type", OracleTypes.NUMBER).put("val", id));
    JsonArray pOut = new JsonArray().add(new JsonObject().put("pos", 1).put("type", OracleTypes.CURSOR));
    DB.cursor(SQL.LIST_CARA_TYPE_DOC_BIN,pIn,pOut, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            try {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(res.result().getJsonArray("1")));
            }catch (Exception e){
                logger.error(e);
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(Error.ERROR_OCCURED.toString()));
            }
        } else {
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(res.cause().getMessage()));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You async api  `getCaraTypeDocBin` implemented wrong. Can you show it?

Comment: thank  you  @zella for  your  response, I added the implementation of  `getCaraTypeDocBin ` in  the  question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In async systems api with futures should be written something like this:

```
private Future<String> loadFromDb() {
    Future<String> f = Future.future();
    //some internal loading from db
    String result = "fromDb";
    //when loading completes, pass it to future result
    f.complete(result);
    return f;
}
```

And how it uses:

```
private void handleSo(RoutingContext routingContext) {

    loadFromDb()
      .map(new Function<String, JsonArray>() {
          @Override
          public JsonArray apply(String fromDb) {
              //map to json
              return new JsonArray(...);
          }
      })
      .setHandler(
        new Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(AsyncResult<JsonArray> result) {
                routingContext.response().end(result.result().toString());
            }
        }
      );
}
```

You are using futures wrong. You example simple and you haven't async chains (where result calculates based on previous result etc), so instead futures, you can simple use callback:

```
private void loadFromDb(Handler<String> handler) {
    String result = "fromDb";
    handler.handle(result);
}

 private void handleSo(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    loadFromDb(new Handler<String>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(String fromDb) {
            routingContext.response().end(new JsonArray(...).toString());
        }
    });
}
```

**Upd** You need collect results from multiple async calls [doc](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_async_coordination). Don't know how to implement it with you callback style api. But with futures it's not problem:

```
private void handleSo(RoutingContext routingContext) {

        List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //make 10 async calls
            futures.add(loadFromDb()
              .map(new Function<String, JsonObject>() {
                  @Override
                  public JsonObject apply(String fromDb) {
                      return new JsonObject().put("data", fromDb);
                  }
              }));
        }
        CompositeFuture.all(futures)
          .map(new Function<CompositeFuture, JsonArray>() {
              @Override
              public JsonArray apply(CompositeFuture compositeFuture) {
                  JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
                  List<JsonObject> jsons = compositeFuture.result().list();
                  jsons.forEach(jsonObject -> array.add(jsonObject));
                  return array;

              }
          })
          .setHandler(new Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>>() {
              @Override
              public void handle(AsyncResult<JsonArray> res) {
                  routingContext.response().end(res.result().toString());
              }
          });
    }
```

Comment: thank  you @zella for your  explanation, i  get  the  perfect  result  from  database and  what  I  want  is  to  make a new  JsonArray which contains the  result  and  send it  to  the client side .

Comment: @HousseinO I was inattentive :) I upd answer

Answer (score 0):

`GET.getCaraTypeDocBin()` runs asynchronously, right?  And I assume there's something time-consuming in there like hitting a remote API?  So the loop will run in milliseconds, kicking off all the requests, and then the "`logger.debugs`" will happen, and only then will the callbacks start to do `caraRefTypeDocBin.add(res.result());`

If I'm right, you should see the results logged before the empty array.

Comment: Thanks @Edward for  you response, yes  it  runs  asynchronously. I want  to  store  the  result into  JsonArray  in  order  to  send it to  the  client side .